# Grunt : use a single task with options to register several tasks

Tags: node.js, gruntjs

I'm missing something obvious with grunt.

Suppose I have two projects duplicating a piece of Gruntfile like this :

```
    // foo/Gruntfile.js
    grunt.loadNpmTask("grunt-develop")
    grunt.initConfig("develop", {
        server: {
            file: "foo.js"
        },
        debug: {
            file: "foo.js",
            nodeArgs: ["--debug"]
        }
    });
    grunt.registerTasks("default", ["develop:server"]
    grunt.registerTasks("debug", ["develop:debug"]
```

In one project, the server file is foo.js, in another one it's bar.js.

*I want to avoid duplicating that part of the Gruntfile*. (NOTE : this is of course just a contrived example, of course. I'm trying to understand if this kind of situation can be changed. In practice, I have two projects with 100+ lines Gruntfile, that share almost exactly the same grunt config except for a few names, paths, etc... )

I tried creating a grunt plugin, so that I would write something like this :

```
 grunt.loadNpmTasks("grunt-my-plugin");

 grunt.initConfig({
    "my_plugin" : {
       main : "foo.js"
    }
 });
```

And I want this plugin to automatically register the "default" and "debug" tasks, using the write main.js

Here is the best I could come up with :

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {

    console.log("Definition of plugin av_dev");

    grunt.registerTask("my_plugin", "Do stuff", function() {

        var main = this.options().main;

        grunt.loadNpmTasks("grunt-develop");

        grunt.config("develop", {
            server: {
                file: main
            },
            debug: {
                file: main,
                nodeArgs: ["--debug"]
            }
        });

        console.log("Registering task foo");

        grunt.registerTask("default", ["develop:server"]);
        grunt.registerTask("debug", ["develop:debug"]);

    });

};
```

This does not work.

Firstly, the 'default' task is not defined.

```
$ grunt
Warning: Task "default" not found. Use --force to continue.
```

Running it 'via' the plugin complains about the availability of loaded grunt task

```
$ grunt my_plugin:default
> Local Npm module "grunt-develop" not found. Is it installed?
```

In my case, the "grunt-develop" plugin is defined as a "devDependencies" in the project that defines my plugin, since I don't want to put it as a dependency of the projects *using* the plugin (do I have to ?)

I've seen other answers that look a bit like this, but nothing where :

- a "plugin" task must register other tasks
- the "plugin" task and the "user" tasks are not in the same project
- the configuration of the "other" tasks is not static

Any idea on this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

After some testing, here is a solution:

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {

   console.log("Definition of plugin av_dev");

   // Move out of your task definition the "grunt-develop" task loading
   grunt.loadNpmTasks("grunt-develop");

   // This task should be called to setup "grunt-develop" just
   // before using it.
   grunt.registerTask("my_plugin", "Do stuff", function() {
       var main = this.options().main;
       grunt.config("develop", {
           server: {
               file: main
            },
            debug: {
                file: main,
                nodeArgs: ["--debug"]
            }
        });
        console.log("grunt-develop setup done.");
    });

    // Also move out the "default" and "debug" task registration
    // And to setup "grunt-develop" just call your configuration
    // task before using it
    grunt.registerTask("default", ["my_plugin", "develop:server"]);
    grunt.registerTask("debug", ["my_plugin", "develop:debug"]);
};
```

The **default** task was not available because you tried to register it from within the **my_plugin** task. So you would have to call the **my_plugin** task to register the **default** to use it...